# Split list of coordinates to lists of coordinates of closed shapes

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry

I want to split a list of coordinate of different closed shapes into lists of coordinate of the closed shapes to remove the linking line of those shapes when plotting it.

Here is an example of what I have:

The contour of an image:

[image: result of find contours]

The stored coordinate (simplified):
[image: coordwithlink]

```
[[28, 235],
 [29, 234],
 [29, 230],
 [30, 229],
 [34, 229],
 [37, 226],
 [37, 222],
 [38, 221],
 [42, 221],
 [43, 220],
 [59, 220],
 [61, 218],
 [61, 214],
 [62, 213],
 [66, 213],
 [67, 212],
 [84, 212],
 [85, 213],
 [89, 213],
 [90, 214],
 [90, 218],
 [91, 219],
 [91, 227],
 [93, 229],
 [97, 229],
 [98, 230],
 [98, 234],
 [99, 235],
 [99, 243],
 [180, 243],
 [180, 195],
 [181, 194],
 [181, 190],
 [182, 189],
 [186, 189],
 [187, 188],
 [195, 188],
 [197, 186],
 [197, 182],
 [198, 181],
 [202, 181],
 [203, 180],
 [212, 180],
 [213, 181],
 [217, 181],
 [218, 182],
 [218, 186],
 [220, 188],
 [228, 188],
 [229, 189],
 [233, 189],
 [234, 190],
 [234, 194],
 [235, 195],
 [235, 219],
 [237, 221],
 [241, 221],
 [242, 222],
 [242, 226],
 [243, 227],
 [243, 255],
 [180, 255],
 [180, 244],
 [99, 244],
 [98, 245],
 [98, 249],
 [97, 250],
 [93, 250],
 [91, 252],
 [91, 255],
 [28, 255],
 [28, 236]]
```

`
And i want to group the coordinate of the two different closed shape to remove the line between this two shapes.
Aiming at plotting something like this:
[image: withoutlink]

So just to separate two closed shape...
I am more interested by hint on how to do it, i am a beginner but i can't figure out the logic to do it.

Thanks !

Comment: how did that even happen? why do you have just a single list of points, for multiple components? don't ask people to clean up a mess you should just prevent from happening in the first place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: oh nonono I just ask for some hint if it was possible didnt want you to clean the mess, its a personnal learning project!
But you did it thanks a lot ! i was retriving all the coordinate where pixel where = 255 for this binary image in a single list, im so stupid, so thats why i had only a list of point ! 
Thanks a lot ! :p

Comment: Are there always two closed polygons in there? Or can there be more? Do you know how many there are beforehand?

Comment: I now use the findcontours function.
there was not always two closed polygons.

Comment: But for my (simple) sample image here i think it's should be easy to do, by retrieving all the pixel coordinate, choose a  coordinate and link it to one of its non used closest neighbor with a condition of distance of one (here without problem of two unused neighbor) and if the conditions are not meet, link this point with the starting point and close the shape, simplify the coordinates then start again..

Comment: if there are two same distance unused neighbor, make a condition like with the general direction of the x previous point i don't know, to technical yet for me.
i mean i just have to read what findcontours() really do ahahah
Thanks anyway :)